How to set the password expiring date for a local user remotely?
I am building an app to manage some local passwords. I already have some functions working and I can get the expiring date of the local user's password.
However I can't seem to find a way to set a new expiring day.
I wanted, for example, to set expiring day for tomorrow. Is it possible?
Here is what I have:
$account = [ADSI]("WinNT://$computer/<username>,user")
$password = New-RandomPassword
$outputPassword.text = $password
$maxPwAge = $account.MaxPasswordAge.Value
$pwAge = $account.PasswordAge.Value
$expiredate = $now.AddSeconds($maxPwAge - $pwAge)
$expiringDate.text = $expiredate

I tried setting a new password max age but I didn't work. My expectations were that setting a max age in seconds for a value that is equivalent to one day would set expiring date for tomorrow.
This needs to work remotely.

This would be so much easier if you had an Active Directory. Then its just a property you can set on the user account. Actually no, you could use group policy to change how often a password expires, and you can set an end date for which the account no longer works.

For local Windows accounts, the trick is to set a local GPO for the maximum password age: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F25388_01/doc.192/f21088/t_change_the_password_expiration_policy_for_windows_user_account.htm#TPSIG-ChangeThePasswordExpirationPolicyFo-90F5EBBB and then set the "password last set" via Set-LocalUser -PasswordLastSet <DateTime> to the correct date time to a previous point in time which makes the "maximum password age" effective when it's that time for the account(s) to expire. These are all trivial items to test and confirm... Good luck!

I want to have the option to set a specific expiration date like LAPS. Any ideas?

Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217615/force-the-password-expiration-date-for-a-local-user-account

You cannot set a specific password expiration date for local accounts in Windows. You can...

Set an ACCOUNT expiration date.
Set a Maximum Password Age.

Together with the tip Vomit IT gave in their comment, you could do maths and effectively create a specific expiration date, by arbitrarily setting a date in the past as the -PasswordLastSet value which, together with the Maximum Password Age, would allow you to set a specific expiration date. To do this you'd need to know the maximum amount of time you'd want one of these accounts to remain active, and then set a Maximum Password Age longer than that. Next, you'd choose the date you want the specific password to expire on, find the difference between the Maximum Password Age and the number of days before you want THIS password to expire, and set -PasswordLastSet that number of days in the past.
So, if the maximum amount of time one of these accounts would need to remain active would be 31 (one month), you set the Maximum Password Age to something like 35. Then, for this specific account you want to expire in one week's time, you'd subtract 7 from 35 to get 28, calculate the date 28 days ago (on July 15th, that would be June 17th, and set THAT date as the -PasswordLastSet value. With this combination of values, the password for this account will expire in 7 days, on July 22nd in our example.
This can all be done pretty simply and automatically in a scripting language of your choice, such as PowerShell.
